# How to specify a sortBy through a javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform() call?

Tags: java, transform, xslt

I'm using javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform() to convert one xml to another through an xsl stylesheet. I would like to programatically set the sorting of the first level of children, but am unsure how to go about it. I've checked out the [docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setOutputProperties%28java.util.Properties%29), but I don't understand which type of property/parameter to use and how to specify in sort:

`<xsl:sort select="*need to get property or parameter to here*"/>`

I am open to other ideas, but would rather not parse the xml result into a w3c document.

**Edit:**
To clarify I am looking to set the sort key and direction for the elements in a `xsl:for-each` tag via the Transformer API.

Comment: It's not clear if you just want to define the sorting expression (very straightforward as Thorbjørn's answer) or you want to pass the sorting key as parameter.

Comment: I want to pass the sorting key as a parameter through the Transformer API. I mention the xsl:sort tag only because that was the only method to sort I could find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="pSortingBy" select="/root/@sorting"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
                <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$pSortingBy]"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<root sorting="prop4">
    <elem1>
        <prop1>A</prop1>
        <prop2>B</prop2>
        <prop3>C</prop3>
        <prop4>D</prop4>
        <prop5>A</prop5>
    </elem1>
    <elem2>
        <prop1>B</prop1>
        <prop2>C</prop2>
        <prop3>D</prop3>
        <prop4>A</prop4>
        <prop5>B</prop5>
    </elem2>
    <elem3>
        <prop1>C</prop1>
        <prop2>D</prop2>
        <prop3>A</prop3>
        <prop4>B</prop4>
        <prop5>C</prop5>
    </elem3>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root sorting="prop4">
    <elem2>
        <prop1>B</prop1>
        <prop2>C</prop2>
        <prop3>D</prop3>
        <prop4>A</prop4>
        <prop5>B</prop5>
    </elem2>
    <elem3>
        <prop1>C</prop1>
        <prop2>D</prop2>
        <prop3>A</prop3>
        <prop4>B</prop4>
        <prop5>C</prop5>
    </elem3>
    <elem1>
        <prop1>A</prop1>
        <prop2>B</prop2>
        <prop3>C</prop3>
        <prop4>D</prop4>
        <prop5>A</prop5>
    </elem1>
</root>
```

**Note**: You could define `pSortingBy` param to be any element name following specifications from your XSLT processor.

**Edit**: I'm not a java expert, but I think you could do:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory transFact =
                       javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance( );
javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
trans.setParameter("pSortingBy", "prop5");
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but you are setting pSortingBy with the input xml document. Is there a way to set pSortingBy through the Transformer API in your example? In the Transformer docs I see setParamter(), but I don't understand how to call it so that I can get the parameter using `$pSortingBy` in the xsl.

Comment: @Adam: That's another questions involving specific XSLT processor feature. And that's why Dimitre has retagged your question.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks, that clarifies how setParameter interacts with the xsd.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to go in a for-each or apply-templates, and you specify the expression to sort on.

From http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <xsl:sort select="artist"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
      </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: right, I understand all the w3schools examples. My question is how to set the blah in `<xsl:sort select="blah" />` to be, for example, title OR artist programatically from the javax Transformer API?